# Django: Block access to not authorized users in CreateView

Tags: python, django

I have a problem for block access to not authorized user in pages dedicated to add new objects. List of that users is stored in many-to-many field in project object and in foreign key field.

Below is models.py

```
class Project(models.Model): 
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="projects_as_owner", null=True)
    project_managers = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="projects_as_pm", blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    date_of_insert = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Milestone(models.Model):
    project_fk = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name="milestones", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    date_of_insert = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And views.py with class I have problem

```
class NewMilestone(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    model = Milestone
    fields = ['name', 'description']
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'p_id'
    template_name = 'main/new_milestone.html'

    # ... two functions, that work good, not important here ...

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(NewMilestone, self).get_queryset()
        project = Project.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['p_id'])
        if(qs.filter(project_fk__owner=self.request.user).exists() or User.objects.filter(id=self.request.user.id).filter(projects_as_pm__id=project.id).exists()):
            return qs
        else:
            return Http404("You are not authenticated to this action")
```

Objective here is here to allow authenticated users (owner and project manager/s) to enter this view and for anybody else show info about declined access.

Problem is that, that method, get_queryset, doesn't block unauthorised users in CreateViev class.

I tried some configurations for that issue, every single one I used had this flaw.

My question here is how to make it work the way I expect from it?

PS. English is not my native language and it was a while since I wrote something, so please be understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the [`LoginRequiredMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin) which is a good thing. But then you didn't set any of the parameters available.

`LoginRequiredMixin` inherits from [`AccessMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.AccessMixin) and you can use all it's parameters with which it shouldn't be too complicated to cover your case.

Here's a possible implementation:

```
class NewMilestone(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    ... 
    # your class attributes 
    ...
    raise_exception = True

    # Returns a permission denied message. Default: empty string
    def get_permission_denied_message(self):
        return "Access is restricted to authenticated users"
```

If you have `raise_exception` set to `True` then the `get_permission_denied_message` method will be called. Otherwise the user will be redirected to the `login_url` which you also would have to declare as a class attribute.